# How to add file as a embedded resources in a exe from another Application programmatically

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have one application which generate xml file, I have to embedded that xml file to another Application (demo.exe) through C# program dynamically. This demo.exe application reads that xml file.

Comment: Is this `demo.exe` a project you've built? Or just some application you've got as an `exe` file?

Comment: i build that demo.exe application.

Comment: Then why can't you add the text file as an item to the project, and then set its Build Action to `embedded resource`?

Comment: Just to be sure: you want to add an Embedded Resource to an application, but the application you want to embed it in first has to generate the file you would like to embed?  

I would say:  
1. build & run the application  
2. generate the file  
3. add the file as an embedded resource  
4. rebuild the application including the embedded resource

Comment: You need to put more detail in your question - I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: How to embed exe file with xml file through C# program

Comment: Why do you have to embed it? Why not just load it from disk? Programatically embedding resources is complex and can be problematic.

Comment: If you want to do it like that then this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107912/programmically-embed-resources-in-a-net-assembly